# LWJGL glGetActiveUniform and glGetActiveAttrib crashes

Tags: java, scala, lwjgl, nio

Following usage of `glGetActiveUniform` crashes both with `nVidia` and `AMD` GPUs, using LWJGL 3.1.3:

```
val strLen = glGetProgrami(program, GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORM_MAX_LENGTH)

val length = Array.ofDim[Int](1)
val size = Array.ofDim[Int](1)
val `type` = Array.ofDim[Int](1)
val name = Array.ofDim[Byte](strLen)
length(0) = 0
size(0) = 0
`type`(0) = 0
name(0) = 0
glGetActiveUniform(program, i, length, size, `type`, java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(name))
```

A bit more verbose version using three API calls works fine to me:

```
val xName = glGetActiveUniformName(program, i)
val xSize = glGetActiveUniformsi(program, i, GL_UNIFORM_SIZE)
val xType = glGetActiveUniformsi(program, i, GL_UNIFORM_TYPE)
```

Recently I hit the same problem with `glGetActiveAttrib`, for which I cannot find any workaround API:

```
val strLen = glGetProgrami(program, GL_ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_LENGTH)

val length = Array.ofDim[Int](1)
val size = Array.ofDim[Int](1)
val `type` = Array.ofDim[Int](1)
val name = Array.ofDim[Byte](64)
glGetActiveAttrib(program, i, length, size, `type`, java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(name))
```

I did not find any examples how this API is supposed to be used. What I am doing wrong? Do I perhaps need some more complex `nio` or other buffer manipulation? (My source code is Scala, I hope this will not be a problem for Java programmers to understand)

Answer (score 0):

My `nio` usage was naive, written without real understanding. After learning a bit, mostly from [Memory management in LWJGL 3](https://blog.lwjgl.org/memory-management-in-lwjgl-3/) and checking how `glGetActiveUniformName` is implemented, the code which works fine is:

```
import org.lwjgl.system._

val stackMem = MemoryStack.stackPush()
try {
  val strLen = glGetProgrami(program, GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORM_MAX_LENGTH)
  val length = stackMem.mallocInt(1)
  val size = stackMem.mallocInt(1)
  val `type` = stackMem.mallocInt(1)
  val name = stackMem.malloc(strLen)

  glGetActiveUniform(program, i, length, size, `type`, name)
  (size.get(0), `type`.get(0), MemoryUtil.memASCII(name, length.get(0)))
} finally {
  stackMem.close()
}
```

The most important difference is LWJGL requires direct NIO buffers to be used.